# Guardar cada resultado de un while en una variable independiente

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código y lo que necesito es guardar cada resultado del while en una variable independiente:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries INNER JOIN finals ON entries.EnId = finals.FinAthlete WHERE finals.FinTournament = '$id' AND finals.FinMatchNo < 16 ORDER BY finals.FinMatchNo DESC";
  $result = mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $result = $mostrar['EnName']." ".$mostrar['EnFirstName'];
  }
```

Necesitaría obtener de esa consulta una variable por cada consulta, es decir:

```
$resultado1 = "primer resultado de la consulta"
$resultado2 = "segundoresultado de la consulta"
...
```

Comment: para que necesitas una variable para cada cosa? el tamaño de las consultas no es fijo y si quieres realizar algo especifico con cada elemento puedes hacer un foreach o incluso ese while, con la variable $mostrar, quiza lo que necesitas es los 3 primeros o algo asi?

Comment: Es que necesito mostrar cada resultado de forma independeiente, no se como podría hacerlo

Comment: ahi mismo lo puedes hacer dentro del while ```print( $mostrar['EnName']." ".$mostrar['EnFirstName']);```

Comment: pero si lo hago de esa manera se van a mostrar los resultados todos juntos, yo necesito usarlos más tarde, cada resultado en un sitio distinto de la página

Comment: entonces dejalo asi, en la variable ```$result``` estan todos los valores, cuando los necesites los recorres con el while

Comment: Pero si yo quiero mostrar unicamente el tercer resultado del while como lo hago

Comment: ahora te pongo el codigo en las respuestas xq es un poco largo

Comment: Es que no funciona asi como dices, en el tercer registro (por ejemplo) puede ir cualquier cosa (y si es que existe), por ende no se debe hacer lo que pides. Un array asociativo es todo lo que necesitas para lo que quieres. Puedes agregar más campos desde la consulta en la BD para distinguir en qué sección del código vas a usar diferentes valores, por ejemplo un `id_disciplina`.

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres hacer eso? La forma correcta es usar un arreglo, y si quieres mostrar el tercer elemento usas `$arreglo[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con un array:

```
$arrayResultados = []
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $arrayResultados[] = $mostrar['EnName']." ".$mostrar['EnFirstName'];
}
```

---

Resultado:

```
$arrayResultados[0] = "primer resultado de la consulta"
$arrayResultados[1] = "segundoresultado de la consulta"
```

Comment: TE AMO, TE ADORO, TE VENERO... LLEVO LITERALMENTE 1 MES BUSCANDO COMO HACER ESTO, NO TE DAS UNA IDEA DE CUANTO TE AMO POR DIOS

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [variables variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php)

```
$num=0;
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $num++;
    $variable = 'resultado' . $num;
    $$variable = $mostrar['EnName']." ".$mostrar['EnFirstName'];
  }
```

Al final, $num te dirá cuantas variables se han generado, y tendrás variables precedidas por $resultado.

Ej.:
Si **`$num = 3`**

```
$resultado1 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$resultado2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$resultado3 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que tienes al principio

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries INNER JOIN finals ON entries.EnId = finals.FinAthlete WHERE finals.FinTournament = '$id' AND finals.FinMatchNo < 16 ORDER BY finals.FinMatchNo DESC";
  $result = mysqli_query($conectar,$sql);
```

despues de eso haces todo lo que tengas que hacer y para obtener el 3er resultado solamente haces esto:

```
//Saltando al 3er valor esto te ahorra el ciclo
  $result->data_seek(2)
  //Obtener la fila
  $tercerValor = $result->fetch_array();
```

Si solo quieres es 3ero puedes poner un LIMIT 3 Al final de la sentencia SQL y optimizas más